# Dúvida de como devo declarar uma função da classe diretamente no HTML

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas para chamar uma função de evento quando renderizo o HTML dinamicamente. Estou usando javascript puro. Ambas funções estão num arquivo de classe `class tabela`, mas quando clico no link que chama a funcao `this.changePage('i')` ela diz que não existe a função. Tem outra forma de eu declarar essa função junto ao HTML?

Segue abaixo a função que monta o template:

```
templatePagination(data, numRegPerPage, page)
{
    let numReg = data.length;
    this.pages = Math.ceil(numReg/numRegPerPage);
    let html = `
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous" onclick="previousPage()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        </li>`;
        for(let i=1; i<= this.pages; i++){
            if(this.pages>1){
                html += `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="${this.changePage('i')}">${i}</a></li>`;
            }
        }
        html += `
        <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next" onclick="nextPage()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>`;

    return html;
}
```

E a função que deveria ser chamada:

```
changePage(pageSelected)
    {
        this.index = pageSelected;
        this.updateTemplate();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desse jeito não tem como testar, mas o que eu posso te adiantar é que do jeito que você está passando a função não vai funcionar.

Você não está de fato declarando uma função para ser invocada no evento `onclick`, você está na verdade invocando a função e passando o retorno para o `onclick`.

Deveria ser

```
`<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="this.changePage(${i})">${i}</a></li>`
```

**Porém** isso também não irá funcionar. Dessa forma que você está gerando o HTML, você está primeiro gerando apenas uma string, e eventualmente interpretando essa string como HTML. Mas strings não entendem o contexto de `this`.

Ao invocar `this.changePage`, o interpretador do código não irá entender que o `this` se refere a um objeto específico, `this.changePage` é apenas uma string, e portanto essa função `changePage` será invocada no contexto do seu elemento (se existir uma função com esse nome), não no seu objeto.

Se você precisa anexar o contexto do seu objeto no evento do `onclick` você precisará de outra abordagem. Não é algo tão simples.

Uma estratégia seria por exemplo fazer o parse da sua string para HTML e então fazer o binding do this na função; basicamente alterando o contexto de `this` para o seu objeto:

```
let html = `
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous" onclick="previousPage()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            </li>`;

            for (let i=1; i<= this.pages; i++) {
                html += `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="this.changePage(${i}")>${i}</a></li>`;
            }

            html += `
            <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next" onclick="nextPage()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>`;

let base = document.createElement('div'); // crio um elemento qualquer como base
base.innerHTML = html; // a string recebida é interpretada como html

base.querySelector('.page-item').forEach(elem => elem.onclick = elem.onclick.bind(this)); // faço o binding do this com a função do evento onclick
return base.firstElementChild; // retorno o html
```

Em nota: como você está retornando um HTML, e não uma string em formato de HTML, para adicionar esse conteúdo a sua página deveria ser via o método `appendChild`.

Comment: Na verdade eu fiz algo parecido com sua reposta. Coloquei o `addEventListener` após renderizar o html: `document.querySelector(`.page-item`).addEventListener("click",()=>{
                    this.changePage(page)
                })`. Assim deu certo. Obrigado.